# how to handle this situation of deadlock in dot net

Tags: .net, multithreading, pooling, concurrency-runtime

suppose, I am having the application for movie seat reservation. scenario is, 3 different request comes at system at exact same time. neither the difference in milliseconds also...
How to handle the request? how to define the critical section and what strategy i need to use.
since all request are on exact same timing, so how to priorities which user should proceed first.

Comment: You don't have to decide. Request thread handling is done by the framework. You just `lock` on the same resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concurrent request will be handled by Framework. 
For accessing shared resource in Code you need to apply [locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) mechanism.
And if your program directly writing to database you need to apply [database transaction locking](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/18/sql-server-detailed-explanation-of-transaction-lock-lock-type-avoid-locks/).

Comment: its good now a days, framework handles almost this control. but enthusiastic to know how it handles.